# Managing IDs in mySQL

Tags: php, mysql, primary-key

I have a users table in my database. The structure is this:

```
fam_id
user
name
username
```

The `fam_id` is primary with AUTO_INCREMENT and goes like 1, 2, 3....
The `user` is the telegram's userID, which I use to identify the users.
The `name` and the `username` are the name and the username in telegram.

Ok, everything is ok, I insert suer, name, username, Mysql generates the fam_id.
But now I need to give to some users the same fam_id.

So my question is: Is there a way to generate a casual id, which mySQL can't give to anyone else, but that can be changed by me to another's user fam_id, having so to users with the same fam_id?

I simply tried by making fam_id AUTO_INCREMENT and changing with UPDATE, but it doesn't work.

Comment: Sounds like you need to normalize your schema to a separate `fam[ily?]` table that has the `auto_increment` and reference that in this user table.

Comment: do you want yo assign the same fam_id to another users?

Comment: @Sammitch Ok, sounds well, but how to do it? And yes, it's Family_is

Comment: @kraysak I need in a second time to give the same fam_id to another user, but would be an update, because every user has its own fam_id when signing up

Comment: There is a lot of solutions. For example, you may add one more column, with the name like `primary_fam_id`. When you need to create secondary row then you assign the `fam_id` of primary row into this column. Primary row may have `primary_fam_id` equal to `fam_id`, or NULL. Really - related rows may form a tree, and even cycles.

Answer (score -1):

Well, because `fam_id` is a primary key and it's `AUTO_INCREMENT`, you can not and should not change it. If you really, really need this funtionality you described, you can add a column, like `my_id`.
Then at your implementation, after you inseted a new user...
`res = MySQL.query(INSERT INTO users ... )`
... MySQL returns a result set. Have a look at it and do something like this:
`temp = res[0].fam_id`
`MySQL.query(UPDATE users SET my_id = temp WHERE fam_id = temp)`

PS: This is js syntax, but I'm sure php has something similar

Comment: Please refer https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer section  before answering any question